# google recaptcha not working scalahosting

Tags: recaptcha

I have two shared hosting account from godaddy and scalahosting, I test this google recaptcha code on both hosting account this code working on godaddy but not in scalahosting, Out put result will be (in this code) "

### You are spammer !

"  So what is this issue ?

Is this web hosting issue ? or ?

```
        <html>
      <head>
        <title>Google recapcha demo - Codeforgeek</title>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Google reCAPTHA Demo</h1>
        <form id="comment_form" action="form.php" method="post">
          <input type="email" placeholder="Type your email" size="40"><br><br>
          <textarea name="comment" rows="8" cols="39"></textarea><br><br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post comment"><br><br>
          <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LftgAUTAAAAAAQkns-ihN6BIbp4Tje5_OF_TSv5"></div>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>



<?php
        $email;$comment;$captcha;
        if(isset($_POST['email'])){
          $email=$_POST['email'];
        }if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
          $email=$_POST['comment'];
        }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
          $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        }
        if(!$captcha){
          echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
          exit;
        }
        $secretKey = "6LftgAUTAAAAAIcMb0tbYDYBN9mi_ZyIydMe2Zug";
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
        $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
        if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
          echo '<h2>You are spammer !t</h2>';
        } else {
          echo '<h2>Thanks for posting comment.</h2>';
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate key for each domain and that domain needs to be added to the recaptcha domain names.

Comment: Yes.. I add everything but not working on scalahosting.

Comment: You have a different key for each one and a different domain for each key at recaptcha?

Comment: Yes... different key for each one and a different domain for each key at recaptcha

Comment: That being the case, I would suggest seeing if scalehosting is using an older version of PHP and if you can select a newer version. I know you can on GD servers but as you mentioned it works fine there and I know GD servers are up to date.

Comment: version of PHP is 5.5 and GD is enable